# Get Previous input and img elements by class name in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get img and input but its only getting Input. Below is code, I have tried find, closest, prev noting working

**HTML**

```
  <img src="/img/no-pic.jpg" alt="no-pic" id="profilePic-0" class="profilePic img-thumbnail" />
  <input class="profilePicUrl" id="yourDetails" name="pic" type="hidden" value="">

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs picUpload"> 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload Photo
    </a>
```

**JS**

```
$('a.picUpload').on('click', function(){
   var inputUrl = $(this).prev('input.profilePicUrl').attr('id'),
       pictureFrame = $(this).find('img.img-thumbnail').attr('id');

   console.log(pictureFrame);
   console.log(inputUrl);
   console.log($(this));
   //openWindow(inputUrl, pictureFrame);
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GjrZ3/) for same scenario, please help I don't know what am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** instead of `.find()` because the image is the sibling of clicked anchor, `.find()` is used to get the descendants of matched elements which is not applicable in your case:

```
pictureFrame = $(this).siblings('img.img-thumbnail').attr('id');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GjrZ3/1/)**

Comment: Hi Felix, what about if i move img out above p tag? how can then i get it.

Comment: Where's your `p` tag?

Comment: sorry everything is inside in p tag

Comment: You can use: `pictureFrame = $(this).closest('p').prev().attr('id');`. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GjrZ3/3/

Comment: Thanks Flex, great help

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) because the `img` is a previous sibling of the `anchor` not its descendant.

```
pictureFrame = $(this).prevAll('img.img-thumbnail').attr('id')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D92gU/)